# long pulling bot telegram fail with making a test

Tags: java, logic, telegram, telegram-bot

So, guys, I'm doing a telegram long polling bot, via Java, via telegram bots API. 
I made an integer for a test to do +1 after good answer and nothing with integer, while answer is wrong.

```
public void onUpdateReceived(Update update) {
    int i=0;
```

on the very beginning of on update receive. 
and when a user starts test he sees a markup keyboard with the first question and 4 answers

```
      else if (message_text.equals("test"))
        {
            SendMessage message = new SendMessage() // Create a message object object
                    .setChatId(chat_id)
                    .setText("Test");
            // Create ReplyKeyboardMarkup object
            ReplyKeyboardMarkup keyboardMarkup = new ReplyKeyboardMarkup();
            // Create the keyboard (list of keyboard rows)
            List<KeyboardRow> keyboard = new ArrayList<>();
            // Create a keyboard row
            KeyboardRow row = new KeyboardRow();
            // Set each button, you can also use KeyboardButton objects if you need something else than text
            row.add("1. М");
            row.add("2. end");

            // Add the first row to the keyboard
            keyboard.add(row);
            // Create another keyboard row
            row = new KeyboardRow();
            row.add("3. К");
            row.add("4. Т");
            keyboard.add(row);
            // Set the keyboard to the markup
            keyboardMarkup.setKeyboard(keyboard);
            // Add it to the message
            message.setReplyMarkup(keyboardMarkup);
            try
            {
                sendMessage(message); // Call method to send the photo
            }
            catch (TelegramApiException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();

            }
        }
        else if (message_text.equals("1. М"))
        {
            i=i+1;
            SendMessage message = new SendMessage() // Create a message object object
                    .setChatId(chat_id)
                    .setText("Test");
            ReplyKeyboardMarkup keyboardMarkup = new ReplyKeyboardMarkup();
            List<KeyboardRow> keyboard = new ArrayList<>();
            KeyboardRow row = new KeyboardRow();
            row.add("1. М");
            row.add("2. end");
            keyboard.add(row);
            row = new KeyboardRow();
            row.add("3. К");
            row.add("4. Т");
            keyboard.add(row);
            keyboardMarkup.setKeyboard(keyboard);
            message.setReplyMarkup(keyboardMarkup);
            try
            {
                sendMessage(message);
            }
            catch (TelegramApiException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();

            }
        }
        else if (message_text.equals("2. end"))
        {
            if (i == 1) {
                SendMessage message = new SendMessage()
                        .setChatId(chat_id)
                        .setText("roflan");

                try {
                    sendMessage(message);
                } catch (TelegramApiException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();

                }
            }
        }
```

if I will write "!=1" , after"2. end" it always shows the result. It does not matter how many time user answer the first button, i+1 doesn't work. Where is a problem with my logic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's forget about Telegram API just to watch what is happening with your `int i` variable.

Everytime the `onUpdateReceived()` is called, `int i` is declaring inside this method and initialising with value `0`.

It looks like this

```
public class Scope {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(getI());
        System.out.println(getI());
    }
    private static int getI() {
        int i = 0;
        i++;
        return i;
    }
}
```

The output will be

```
1
1
```

To make your program work as you expect you should declare `int i` outside of `onUpdateReceived()` scope. The most obvious way is creating a static variable.

```
public class Scope {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(getI());
        System.out.println(getI());
        System.out.println(getI());
        System.out.println(getI());
    }
    private static int i = 0;
    private static int getI() {
        i++;
        return i;
    }
}
```

The output will be

```
1
2
3
4
```

So, now your code should look like this one

```
public class Bot extends TelegramLongPollingBot {

    private static int i = 0;

    public void onUpdateReceived() {
        /*...*/
        else if (update.hasMessage() && update.getMessage().hasText() && update.getMessage().getText().equals("1. M")) {
            i++;
        } else if (update.hasMessage() && update.getMessage().hasText() && update.getMessage().getText().equals("1. end")) {
            System.out.println(i);
        }
        /*...*/
    }

    public String getBotToken() {
        return "...";
    }

    public String getBotUsername() {
        return "...";
    }
}
```

Comment: thx, that worked. I knew there is no problems with API, so i made a question with logic on tegs.

Comment: now, how do I join it for a single chat_id, either way, it becomes for everyone and every time while my bot is running.